# .NET3.5 Webservice authentication: what to choose?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

I have a site on .NET 3.5 platform with implemented custom authentication for site users.

Now I'm going to provide site api for users. 
Probably WSDL (as it has good integration with Visual Studio)

Api will will provide access to private info, so to access it API user should be authenticated.

Question 1 is: what webservice type better to use for .NET 3.5 (WSDL or something else?)

Question 2: how to make secure authentication for that webservice? (Authentication should be done using user login/pass from the site DB)

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try regular WebServices with SoapHeaderAuthentication.

Refer to: 
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Securing-ASP-Net-Web-Services-with-Forms-Authentication.aspx

Comment: I used authorization by IP + secret key passed to each request